# How to disable ethernet check during boot

Tags: boot, networking, ethernet, raspberrypi

I have Ubuntu 16 running on a Raspberry Pi 3 mobile platform, and if it's not connected to ethernet, and the wifi's out of range during boot, it takes about 15 minutes to boot, since it appears Ubuntu has a very long timeout while it waits to bring up eth0 or wlan0. I've tested this repeatedly, and when the boot takes forever, I find plugging in an ethernet cable magically makes boot completely instantly.

How do I disable this, so Ubuntu boots up quickly, regardless of network connectivity? I'm using Network Manager, which is excellent at re-establishing a wlan0 connection onces an recognized SSID is detected.

Comment: I am deleting my answer as I don't have an answer for you. I cannot duplicate your issue, and I don't want to keep guessing what your issue is.

Comment: @Terrance, Actually, it looks like your solution works as well. Changing the conf in `/etc/network/interfaces` for eth0 from auto to manual also stopped the hanging during boot.

Comment: I actually like your answer that you wrote.  I didn't stop to think about having network ports listed in the interfaces file.  That would also explain why I couldn't duplicate your issue, as I don't have those listed in my interfaces file.  Nice find!  =)

Answer (score 2):

Fire up your favorite text editor: `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.targets.wants/networking.service`

Find and edit this line with your meat fidgets: `TimeoutStartSec=5min`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that eth0 was hardcoded in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so networking always tried to bring it up at boot.

Since I'm using Network Manager, I found the easiest solution was to remove all the eth0 entries from `/etc/network/interfaces`. This makes Network Manager auto-detect it and bring it up if present.

Edit: Even with the eth0 entry removed the `/etc/network/interfaces`, booting was still slow (even though it was faster than before). I found adding the entry back, but changing it from "auto" to "manual" made boot happen almost instantly.

Comment: I have witnessed the slowness that you have mentioned in the servers I work on when they have an interface unplugged but enabled.  And you are correct that they hang for a short time.   So, good research that you have done.  =)

Answer (score 1):

The sleep commands waiting for the network can be changed in the file

```
/etc/init/failsafe.conf
```

Comment: That file doesn't exist on my system.

Comment: Good to know, the ARM version of Ubuntu must be doing that elsewhere.